# Does write permission over a windows service always imply privilege escalation?

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation, windows-permissions

Context:

Doing a lab pentest on a windows VM, I got a shell as LocalService. I modified the binpath to execute a meterpreter. Then I changed the SERVICE_START_NAME to "LocalSystem" by doing:

```
sc config upnphost obj= "LocalSystem" password= ""
```

I got a reverse shell as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

I understand that this works only because Localsystem has no password set. If I were to run this service as "John", I would need to type John´s pass.

So, does this mean that I can own any system just by having write access to one service (and the ability to start it)?  <=> Being LocalService implies easy SYSTEM?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that this works only because Localsystem has no password
>   set.

Not correct. The misconfiguration here is the missing write protection for the service object. It has nothing to do with the password.

> So, does this mean that I can own any system just by having write
>   access to one service

Yes. This is a classical privilege escalation vector on Windows. Services must be write protected for non-admin users.